# Domain Controller Roles not properly configured

Tags: domain-controller

I added a W2008R2 domain controller to a domain which previously had two W2003 domain controllers.  I want to demote and remove the W2003 server that held the primary roles.  I successfully transferred the FSMO roles to the W2008 server. The W2008 server holds a GC role along with the old W2003 primary server. To be safe I have not yet demoted the W2003 server that held the primary roles.

I powered down the W2003 server that held the primary roles and within about half an hour the workstations had trouble finding the domain.  Obviously another action(s) of some sort needs to be initiated to move a role(s) to the new W2008 server but I can't figure out what it is.  Appreciate your advice.

Comment: I'll give you a clue: It's probably related to DNS.